# python - how to mention a user in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So i wanted to make a command where you type cookie and the bot tags you with '@' and sends you a cookie emoji. I tried making the code for the mention part but i keep getting an error about ctx being a required argument that is missing. Here is my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def cookie(self, ctx):
    await self.bot.say("@{} :cookie:".format(ctx.message.author.id))
```

Comment: is your command in a class? if it isn't, then you don't need to remove `self` from your cookie parameters to fix the ctx requirement error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, removing `self` fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Cool! You might want to press the checkmark to mark this question as answered